# change the output of the php query result as array

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP code which has the following output:

```
[{"stockdata":29655.88482666}]
```

And I need to change the code on my php to get the result in this format:

```
[{"data": [29655.88482666]}]
```

This is the code of my php:

```
<?php


function getArraySQL(){
$startd = "29964";
$endd = "29968";
$dsn = "prueba";
$connect = odbc_connect( $dsn, '', '' );
$query = "

Select SUM(TON_DESCARGADO) as stockdata
    from 
        (Select unit,[load],enum_LOAD.[name],SUM(dumptons) as TON_DESCARGADO
        from hist_dumps inner join hist_loclist on hist_dumps.shiftindex = hist_loclist.shiftindex
                                       and hist_dumps.loc = hist_loclist.locid
                inner join enum_LOAD on hist_dumps.[load] = enum_LOAD.[num]
        where hist_dumps.shiftindex between '$startd' and  '$endd'

GROUP BY loc,UNIT,unit#,[load],enum_LOAD.[name])TEMP1
where unit = 'Stockpile'
GROUP BY unit
order BY UNIT";


if(!$rs = odbc_exec($connect, $query)) die();

$rawdata = array();

$i=0;

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs))
{   
$rawdata[$i] = $row;
$i++;
}
odbc_close( $connect );
return $rawdata;    
};
$stockdata = getArraySQL();
echo json_encode(($stockdata), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

What need to be changed to get the correct format? Should I do something to improve the code of my php?

How should I write it if I connect php to SQL server via `PDO` and get the same result? (just an optional doubt)

Comment: Could you `var_dump` your `$rawdata` please?

Comment: You haven't stated why you want to change it in that format, because **{data: [<some_value>]}** means your _data key_ represents an array.

Comment: because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900565/highchart-load-the-chart-but-not-the-json-data

Comment: array(0) { } [[{"stockdata":29655.88482666}]]

Comment: I need to put the data on a highchart gauge, and doesn't accept the output generated by php

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["stockdata"]=> string(18) "29655.884826660156" } } [[{"stockdata":29655.88482666}]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find custom output in `json_encode`, so if you want to customize the output of array , you would need to prepare it.
I assumed the data exists at zero index (`0`). 
So, I use `$stockdata[0]` 
for `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` replace, used `(float)`

here is the preparation of output to send exactly you want.

```
$stockdata = getArraySQL();
$Numeric_data = (float) $stockdata[0];
$data = '[{"data": ['.$Numeric_data.']}]';
echo $data;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/WZWgaS)

Comment: add `echo '<pre>';print_r($stockdata);echo '</pre>';` right after the `$stockdata = getArraySQL();`

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => 29655.884826660156
        )

)
[{"data": [1]}]

Comment: i think that the problem isn't of he php. Probably the Highchart require only the numeric value from the json....  I will see how to do that